# android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, service, crash, android-mapview

I have a Service that acts like an overlay with a chathead (like facebook messenger) when the user tap on this chatHead I pop a MapView (v2)

It works for the majority of my users, but in the bug report all the Xiaomi Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 users have the same crash

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service
>   com.package.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Configuration
>   android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object
>   reference at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Configuration
>   android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object
>   reference at android.view.SurfaceView.init(SurfaceView.java) at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.(SurfaceView.java) at
>   maps.V.x.(Unknown Source) at maps.V.v.(Unknown Source) at
>   maps.D.v.(Unknown Source) at maps.D.v.a(Unknown Source) at
>   maps.ad.ae.a(Unknown Source) at maps.ad.u.a(Unknown Source) at
>   maps.ad.R.a(Unknown Source) at
>   wc.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:66) at
>   android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java) at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.a.e$a$a.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$a.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.e.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.c.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.g(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.a(Unknown Source)

The code that seems to fail is here

```
    this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    this.myView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_map, null);
    this.mapView = (MapView) myView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    this.mapView.onCreate(null);
    this.mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

The line that throws this error is

**this.mapView.getMapAsync(this);**

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

Try turning Hardware acceleration on in manifest

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

it worked for me
source: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9071

Comment: This solved my NullpointerException I was getting in OnElementChanged() in a CustomMapRenderer while using Xamarin :D Thanx man!

Comment: WORKED! THANK YOU~

Comment: This is not correct android:hardwareAccelerated is enable by default