# System.NullReferenceException during OnElementChanged() in CustomMapRenderer

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am writing an app using Xamarin. Part of the app includes a map that displays tracking points. Everything works perfectly, except when the app in run on a Xiaomi Redmi 4A using Android 6.0.1.

I get a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I try to run my OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e).

My code:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _customMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            _unitViewModel = (UnitViewModel)_customMap.BindingContext;
            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);

            _unitViewModel.TrackingPositions.CollectionChanged += TrackingPositions_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
```

The exception is thrown at base.OnElementChanged(e). If this part gets enclosed in a try catch, the same exception is thrown at ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);

Comment: Does your device have google play services installed? Certain devices don't ship with it as default depending on the Android provider. Google maps can't work without that installed on the device.

Comment: Exactly, as SuavePirate said, please ensure that your device has google play services installed. And if it is installed and the problem still happens, please post your code of your custom map in PCL.

Comment: I have a if (CheckPlayService()) that checks before I start, even before registering for GCM. I also opened Google Maps and it works perfectly fine. I have also found that the app runs fine on Samsung S4, Wileyfox Swift, Samsung J3 (?) just to name a few. Problem seems to be resticted to only the Xiaomi.

Comment: code in CustomMap.cs: `using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace Celmax
{
    public class CustomMap : Map, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    }
}
`

Comment: My problem was solved by enabling android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the android manifest. Seems like the Xiaomi was struggling a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by enabling android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the Android Manifest file. This might help to solve a couple of NullPointerExceptions of the same nature on a range of devices.

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/Logo" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Link to where the solution was first posted: [android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278242/android-content-res-resources-getconfiguration-on-a-null-object-reference). This guy was the real MVP :D